# Is it possible to get HTTP status of created tab by browser.tabs.create({ url: 'https://exampleforerror.com/', active: false })?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome-extension

there question is how to get http status code of newly created tab without fetch/XMLHttpRequest?

I tried with

```
  browser.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function (tabID, changeInfo, tab) {
    console.log(changeInfo)
    if (tabID === tabId && tab.status === 'complete') console.log(tab)
  })
```

but it doesn't return any error status

Comment: It looks like you can't, as [this answer shows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/220231/accessing-the-web-pages-http-headers-in-javascript). I know that's about regular web pages, but a good rule of thumb is when there's no explicit extensions API, try the web one.

I tried playing around with the [Headers API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Headers) in an extension page (really just assuring myself that it works the way I think). I'm not sure of any of this, which is why I'm answering in a comment.

Comment: You can use browser.webRequest API.